# Bash How to find directories of given files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with several subfolders and in some of those subfolders I have text files example_1.txt, example_2.txt and so on. example_1.txt may be found in subfolder1, some subfolders do not contain text files.

How can I list all directories that contain a text file starting with `example`?

I can find all those files by running this command

`find .  -name "example*"`

**But what I need to do is to find the directories these files are located in?** I would need a list like this `subfolder1, subfolder4, subfolder8` and so on. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: `find . -name "example*" -exec dirname {} \;`?

Comment: `find . -name "example*" -printf "%h\n"` if using GNU find.

Comment: Pipe the output from @Biffen's `find` command through `uniq` to filter out duplicates (as needed).

Comment: Don't mix usage of the words "folder" and "directory".  If you are talking about a gui artifact, call it a "folder".  If you are talking about an object in the file system, call it a "directory".  Directories (the filesystem object) do not contain files. Folders (the real life physical object) do contain files.  This is why the object in the file system is not called a "folder".  The gui artifact is called a "folder" because....well, because someone in marketing didn't understand that directories do not contain files.

Answer (score 0):

You must be use the following  command,

```sh
find . -name "example*" | uniq -u | awk -F / '{print $2}'
```

Comment: You could improve this by [edit]ing and adding a bit of explanation, so that people learn from the answer instead of just copying and pasting from the interwebs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, why the `uniq`? When would you ever have the same path multiple times? Will that `awk` work for all kind of depths? Why not use `dirname` instead?

Answer (score 0):

- find all files in subfolders with mindepth 2 to avoid this folder (.)
- get dirname with xargs dirname
- sort output-list and make folders unique with sort -u
- print only basenames with awk (delimiter is / and last string is $NF). add "," after every subfolder
- translate newlines in blanks with tr
- remove last ", " with sed

---

```
list=$(find ./ -mindepth 2 -type f -name "example*"|xargs dirname|sort -u|awk -F/ '{print $NF","}'|tr '\n' ' '|sed 's/, $//')

echo $list

flow, over, stack
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `find` command that prints only the directories path.

Than sort the paths.

Than remove duplicates.

```
find . -type f -name "example*" -printf "%h\n"|sort|uniq
```